# jQuery selector not working well with jquery-mobile datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, triggers, datepicker

In my html I have two different datepickers, inside two different divs. I want to do something when selecting a day from the datepicker, like this:

```
$('#details1 tr .ui-body-c').on('click', function(){
    $('#details1 .hasDatepicker').hide();
    if($('#date1').val()!="")
    {
        var day=new Date($('#date1').val());
        day.setHours(23);
        day.setMinutes(59);
        day.setSeconds(59);

        getDayData(day);
    }
});
```

But clicking on the day is not triggering the click event. If I remove the #details1 from the selector the event triggers, but with both of the datepickers.

Here's a link to the datepicker plugin: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

**EDIT:** It seems that the table jquery-mobile datepicker creates is not detected inside the page. I even tried this:

```
$('html tr .ui-body-c').on('click', function(){
   $('#details1 .hasDatepicker').hide();
    if($('#date1').val()!="")
    {
        var day=new Date($('#date1').val());
        day.setHours(23);
        day.setMinutes(59);
        day.setSeconds(59);

        getDayData(day);
    }
});
```

And is not working. Also did `var a = $('.datepicker-calendar').parent()` and got [] as a result.

Any thoughts on why is this happening and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by editing the `jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js` file, adding a custom class to  elements.

```
if(options.altField!=undefined)
    $(dp).attr('id', options.altField.split('#')[1] + '1');
```

And then in `function updateDatepicker(){`

```
$( ".ui-datepicker-calendar td", dp ).addClass("ui-body-c "+$(dp).attr('id')+'2');
```

So if my date input's id is "myDatePicker", each td on the calendar will have class "myDatePicker12", and I can do this:

```
$('.myDatePicker12').on('click', function(){
   $('#details1 .hasDatepicker').hide();
    if($('#date1').val()!="")
    {
        var day=new Date($('#date1').val());
        day.setHours(23);
        day.setMinutes(59);
        day.setSeconds(59);

        getDayData(day);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** My apologies, I should have looked closer at what the mobile version of datepicker does. Your issue is most likely due to it adding the table to the DOM later on, you will need to delegate the event from something static eg:

```
$('#details1').on('click', 'tr .ui-body-c', function(){
```

---

If the mobile version of datepicker is the same as the normal jQuery UI you would be better off using the onSelect event when you first initialize it, something like:

```
$('#details1').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        inst.input.hide();
        var day=new Date(dateText);
        day.setHours(23);
        day.setMinutes(59);
        day.setSeconds(59);

        getDayData(day);
    }
});​
```

This event is triggered when you select a day, dateText is the value it will put into the input (no need to get it yourself) and inst is the datepicker instance which contains the input in question (inst.input).

Comment: This doesn't work. When the page loads the jquery-mobile datepicker script generates a datepicker on each input type="date". It's some nested divs with a table inside, and binds a click events to select the day you clicked, so the .datepicker method doesn't work.

Comment: #details1 is my wrapper div for that page. Also tried with other divs closer to the table but got nothing.

Comment: Added an edit to the top of my answer, it will be because the elements you are targetting are being added to the DOM later on, meaning the click is never bound to them from your original code.

Comment: Still not working with that, but now I think is .on method's fault. I even tried $('body').on('click', 'tr .ui-body-c', function(){ and did not work. I'm using jquery 1.7.1 (with 1.7.2 I get an error on start)

Comment: Is it something to do with how jQuery mobile works? Aren't basically all page loads AJAX? Is there some specific method they advise you use for binding events like this?